# line count with in the text files having multiple lines and single lines

Tags: sql, linux

i am using `UTL_FILE` utility in oracle to get the data in to csv file. here i am using the script.

so i am getting the set of text files

case:1

sample of output in the test1.csv file is

```
"sno","name"
"1","hari is in singapore
ramesh is in USA"
"2","pong is in chaina
chang is in malaysia
vilet is in uk"
```

now i am counting the number of records in the test1.csv by using linux commans as

```
egrep -c "^\"[0-9]" test1.csv
```

here i am getting the record count as

```
2      (ACCORDING TO LINUX)
```

but if i calculate the number of records by using select * from test;

```
 COUNT(*)
----------                 (ACCORDING TO DATA BASE)
    2
```

case:2

sample of output in the test2.csv file is

`"sno","name","p"
   "","",""
   "","","ramesh is in USA"
   "","",""`

now i am counting the number of records in the test2.csv by using linux commans as

```
egrep -c "^\"[0-9]" test2.csv
```

here i am getting the record count as

```
0      (ACCORDING TO LINUX)
```

but if i calculate the number of records by using select * from test;

```
 COUNT(*)
----------                 (ACCORDING TO DATA BASE)
    2
```

can any body help me how to count the exact lines in case:1 and case:2 using the single command

thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not understandable. pls reformat it.

Comment: Yeah, it needs a cleanup. I've made my best guess as to what you want in my answer below, but you need to ask clearer questions.

Comment: Looking at your new edit: `egrep -c "^\"[0-9]" test2.csv` works fine for both test files when I test it. Are you sure that's what you where running?

Comment: there is answer for case1 only if i apply the same logic to case 2 it is not giving the exact row count .

Comment: please help me for case2

Comment: Did the previous answer help you? Could you format your questions as well? It is hard to go through such big blocks of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Columns in both case is different. To make it generic I wrote a perl script which will print the rows. It generates the regex from headers and used it to calculate the rows. I assumed that first line always represents the number of columns.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

open(FH, $ARGV[0]) or die "Failed to open file";

# Get coloms from HEADER and use it to contruct regex 
my $head = <FH>;
my @col = split(",", $head); # Colums array
my $col_cnt = scalar(@col);  # Colums count

# Read rest of the rows 
my $rows;
while(<FH>) {
$rows .= $_;
}

# Create regex based on number of coloms
# E.g for 3 coloms, regex should be 
# ".*?",".*?",".*?" 
# this represents anything between " and "
my $i=0;
while($i < $col_cnt) {
$col[$i++] = "\".*?\"";
}
my $regex = join(",", @col);

# /s to treat the data as single line 
# /g for global matching
my @row_cnt = $rows =~ m/($regex)/sg; 
print "Row count:" . scalar(@row_cnt);
```

Just store it as `row_count.pl` and run it as `./row_count.pl filename`

Comment: thank you .... i tried awk , wc-l ,egrep and lot but it is really dynamic thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`egrep -c test1.csv` doesn't have a search term to match for, so it's going to try to use `test1.csv` as the regular expression it tries to search for. I have no idea how you managed to get it to return 2 for your first example.

A useable `egrep` command that will actually produce the number of records in the files is `egrep '"[[:digit:]]*"' test1.csv` assuming your examples are actually accurate.

```
timp@helez:~/tmp$ cat test.txt
"sno","name"
"1","hari is in singapore
ramesh is in USA"
"2","pong is in chaina
chang is in malaysia
vilet is in uk"

timp@helez:~/tmp$ egrep -c '"[[:digit:]]*"' test.txt
2

timp@helez:~/tmp$ cat test2.txt
"sno","name"
"1","hari is in singapore"
"2","ramesh is in USA"

timp@helez:~/tmp$ egrep -c '"[[:digit:]]*"' test2.txt
2
```

Alternatively you might do better to add an extra value to your `SELECT` statement. Something like `SELECT 'recmatch.,.,',sno,name FROM TABLE;` instead of `SELECT sno,name FROM TABLE;` and then `grep` for `recmatch.,.,` though that's something of a hack.

Answer (score 0):

In your second example your lines do not start with `"` followed by a number. That's why count is `0`. You can try `egrep -c "^\"([0-9]|\")"` to catch empty first column values. <del>But in fact it might be simpler to count all lines and remove `1` because of the header row.</del>

<del>e.g.</del>
 <del>count=$(( $(wc -l test.csv) - 1 ))</del>

Comment: This will fail for case1 in which single row is divided into multiple lines.

Comment: @SanketParmar, actually didn't notice he wants to work on multi-line splits. My original suggestion still works though. But I like your solution. Haven't tested it but +1 for it.